# problema con decimal en java

Tags: java, double

tengo un producto de dos números

```
double resultado = XN1 * XN;
```

pero ese resultado quisiera añadirle un 0.resultado, lo hago con este método

```
String convertirdecimal(String cad) {
    String cad2 = "0." + cad;
    return cad2;
}
```

al que le paso la cadena que vendría siendo el resultado, pero luego cuando me regresa el resultado eso lo transformo en un `double`, el problema viene cuando es un resultado como `170` que al añadir el `0.170` al transformarlo en `double` queda `0.17` y no se el porque, no se si habría una mejor manera de añadirle el `0.` al resultado

Comment: 0.170 = 0.17.. cual es el problema?

Comment: necesito el 0 @gbianchi

Comment: al final de la cadena? entonces pq lo volves a pasar a doble?

Comment: me dices hacer doble conversión? @gbianchi

Comment: no.. sigo sin entender el problema.. el double nunca va a tener un cero que no sirve en su visualizacion.. para que necesitas el cero?? es un problema de vista?? o de que??? podrias agregar toda la informacion de pq necesitas ese cero, de donde partis y a donde queres llegar?

Comment: @gbianchi 0.17 es lo mismo que 0.170?

Comment: numericamente si!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr utilizando [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) que se utiliza para dar los formatos a numeros dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Si lo utilizas de la siguiente manera:

```
DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("####.####");
// Imprime esto con cuatro decimales, es decir: 7,1234
System.out.println (formateador.format (7.12342383));
```

Recorta los numeros hasta lo definido en el formato. Si reemplazas el `#` por `0` los numeros se rellenan con `0` las posiciones que tengas definidas en el formato.

```
DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("0000.0000");
// Imprime con 4 cifras enteras y 4 decimales: 0001,8200
System.out.println (formateador.format (1.82));
```